# Facebook pixel script in google page speed insight

Tags: pagespeed-insights, facebook-pixel

We are facing 2 problems when we use the Facebook conversion pixel script in our site, while check the performance with Google page speed insights.

This following scripts loading automatically, but this script causes trouble in 2 areas in page speed insight.
https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/166971126971821

1. Comes in unused script section.
   [image]
2. Efficient cache policy not set.
   [image]

Please explain how these 2 problems can be addressed.

Comment: I have pixel all over my e-commerce site and no such error. Mine is being loaded through the Facebook for Woocommerce plugin and doesn't show up in any Insights reports.